# Can a limit $x\to a$ exist if $x=a$ is the furthest point on a function?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Take the function $f(x) = x$, but the furthest defined point to the right on the graph is $x=2$. After that, the line of the graph simply terminates.

Does $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}$ exist in this situation? $x$ clearly approaches $2$ in the graph, but it only approaches from the left. It doesn't approach from the right since there is no line of the graph there. Building on this, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}$ does not exist, then I suppose the function is not continuous at $x=2$?

This seems like an elementary question, so apologies if this has been asked elsewhere (I searched around but couldn't find a matching question).

Comment: When we talk about function, we need to specify the domain where this function is defined on. In our case $f(x)=x$ is defined on, say $[0,2]$, since it was not specified what it would be when $x>2$. In this case we can still speak of one sided limit, where we only look at what value $f$ is approaching to when x is approaching from the left.

Comment: So the only reason we generally look at the left-sided and right-sided limits of a function is because the function's domain is usually defined on both sides? If it's not, then there's no reason to look at both sides?

Comment: It is better to think of it this way: If the function is not defined on one of the sides, then we cannot even talk about the usually two-sided limit. The reason we look at two-sided limit is because the notion is related to continuous functions.

Comment: @lEm So does this imply that the limit can exist if f(x) is only defined on one side of x=a, but f(x) is not continuous at x=a?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545193/reconciling-rudins-limit-definitions-one-sided-limit-uniqueness, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264609/if-there-is-only-one-one-sided-limit-the-limit-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

*More general subsets*

Apart from open intervals, limits can be defined for functions on arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, as follows. Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on a subset $S$ of the real line. Let $p$ be a limit point of $S$—that is, $p$ is the limit of some sequence of elements of $S$ distinct from $p$. The limit of $f$, as $x$ approaches $p$ from values in $S$, is $L$ if, for every $ε > 0$, there exists a $δ > 0$ such that $0 < |x − p| < δ$ and(!) $x ∈ S$ implies $|f(x) − L| < ε$.

This limit is often written

$\displaystyle L={\underset {x\in S}{\lim _{x\to p}}}f(x)$.

The condition that f be defined on S is that S be a subset of the domain of f. This generalization includes as special cases limits on an interval, as well as left-handed limits of real-valued functions (e.g., by taking S to be an open interval of the form $\displaystyle (-\infty ,a)$), and right-handed limits (e.g., by taking S to be an open interval of the form $\displaystyle (a,\infty )$). It also extends the notion of one-sided limits to the included endpoints of (half-)closed intervals, so the Square root function f(x)=√x can have limit 0 as x approaches 0 from above.
(End of citation from Wikipedia)

**Conclusion:** The definition of Limits *heavily* depends in the domain of definition for the function to be investigate.